# Вывод скриншотов с ip камер и данных 1С

Tags: php, python, 1с

При взвешивании авто на автовесовой (Тара, Брутто) данные попадают в 1С 8.3 
Как вывести значение при взвешивании и скриншоты с четырех IP камер на веб страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - на стороне 1С организовать http-сервис, к которому будет стучаться веб-страница. Соответственно, 1С будет отдавать данные по картинке и весу.

Answer (score 0):

Пример примитивный, усложняй от своих реалий:

```
Страница = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;

Страница.ДобавитьСтрока("<html>");
Страница.ДобавитьСтрока("<body>");
Страница.ДобавитьСтрока("Результаты взвешивания:");

//твой код с запросом к камере 1

Результат =  HTTPСоединение.Получить(ТвойHTTPЗапрос1);
ПутьКФайлу1 =  КаталогВременныхФайлов() +"какое-то имя.jpg";
ДД = Результат.ПолучитьТелоКакДвоичныеДанные();
ФОтка = ПоместитьВоВременноеХранилище(ДД);
ДД.Записать(ПутьКФайлу1);

//Повторяешь для каждой из камер, получаешь 4 файла картинки.
//Не обязательно писать во временный каталог, решай где тебе удобно хранить.

Страница.ДобавитьСтрока("<img src="ПутьКФайлу1" alt=""+ ПолученыйРанееВес +"" />");
//выводишь по аналогии еще 3 фото

Страница.ДобавитьСтрока("</body>");
Страница.ДобавитьСтрока("/<html>");
Страница.Записать("C:\index.html");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. а как организовать ето не на стороне 1С? к примеру  сервер 1С находится в сети  по адресу 10.0.0.3 а веб сервер находится в по другому IP?

Comment: Зависит от того, кто будет выступать инициатором. Если веб сервер, то обращение к http-сервису, как предлагал Павел, 1с вернет картинку и вес и уже на стороне вебсервера реализуется вывод. 
Если инициатором должна быть 1с, навскидку пару вариантов:
тот же сервис на стороне сервера, куда нужно будет стучаться, передавая инфу тем же JSON.
Костыльно, но будет работать: любой буфер(файл, бд), куда 1с будет ложить актуальную инфу а веб считывать. в зависимости от того, что нужно по задаче - кодом помогу